# Frequency vs amplitude for electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism

As we know frequency is closely related to wavelength, that means, if we change the frequency, we are changing wavelength.

Let assume for damped oscillation, where amplitude gets lower and therefore the energy becomes very less.  Since $E= h f$ refers that energy is related to frequency, **can we say that frequency, amplitude and  wavelength are  dependent on each other?**

Comment: Energy and wavelength are related, the relation $k\equiv k(\omega)$ being known as dispersion relation. The amplitude is a little trickier because, given a general solution to the wave equation $f$, it is defined as $f^*f$ and this can also not be directly expressed in terms of $k$ in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

No. Actually $E=nhf $, where n is the number of photons. As n decreases amplitude decreases leaving frequency and wavelength unchanged.

Comment: but for different energy we can have different color.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. For a single photon, $E=hf$  and $c=\lambda f$. $E, c$ and $\lambda$ don't decrease (in vacuum).

Comment: @Gert  But it can't be in a vacuum because he specified damped oscillations which suggests that absorption is taking place.  I assumed his h was Planck's constant, but if so he seems to be mixing quantum and classical concepts.  That's why I inserted the photon number and assumed the number decreased as absorption took place.